# border-spacing with rounded 1px borders

Tags: html, css, html-table, border-spacing

I can't find a matching answer for that.

HTML:

```
<table class="table1">
    <tr>
        <td class="red header" colspan="4">
            Table1 header</td>
    </tr>
    ...
    <tr>
        <td class="red footer" colspan="4">Footer</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="table2">
    <tr>
        <td class="red header" colspan="4">
            Table2 header</td>
    </tr>
    ...
    <tr>
        <td class="red footer" colspan="4">Footer</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.table1 {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table2 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.footer {
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.header {
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-top-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uXUnm/

As you can see, `table1` has 2px border (I'd like 1px), `table2` doesn't have rounded borders. `border-collapse:collapse;` fixes the first issue caused by `border-spacing: 0;` but breaks the roundings. Can anyone tell me a way to fix both issues without messing with `:first-child`, `last-child` etc. selectors?

Comment: BTW, that's not how you do table headers or footers.  There's elements like `thead`, `tfoot`, `tbody`, `caption`, and `th` that have semantic meaning and should be used over a bland colspanned td.

Comment: I'm doing it for MyBB which uses only thead and tbody in default skin, not even in all tables. Would take a while to convert everything to those. So I was hoping for an ultimate CSS or JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

here is my fixed css:

```
table {
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
table td:first-child, table td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child){
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
table tr:first-child td, table tr:not(:last-child) td {
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

table thead tr:first-child  td:first-child {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
}

table thead tr:first-child  td:last-child {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
}
table tbody tr:last-child  td:first-child {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}

table tbody tr:last-child  td:last-child {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}
```

you can set border-radius: 5px; any value and it will work perfectly!